# Is there a efficient way of finding the max, min, odd, and even numbers all in one code?

Tags: applescript

```
set numberList to {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
set max to 0
repeat with x in numberList
    if x > max then set max to x
end repeat
display dialog max

set numberList to {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
set min to 3
repeat with x in numberList
    if x < min then set min to x
end repeat
display dialog min

set numberList to {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
repeat with i in numberList
    if i mod 2 = 0 then
        display dialog "These numbers are even " & i
    else
        display dialog "These numbers are odd " & i
    end if
end repeat
```

Is there a more efficient way of determining the odd, even, maximum, and minimum values of a list using AppleScript?

Comment: AppleScript doesn't really have anything available other than combining everything into a single repeat loop.

Comment: Okay, so I would just to have a bunch of if and else if statement to display the odd, even, min, and max.

Comment: Yes - @vadian threw in some AppleScriptObjC to use various Cocoa array and filter methods, but for plain AppleScript you could include all your tests in a single repeat loop.

Comment: I think you missed a significant point that _@CJK_ included in his solution to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58938393/finding-the-max-in-applescript#answer-58949649). The `set max to 0` part in this question should be changed to `set max to some item in numberList` because if `numberList` was `set numberList to {-1, -20}` then currently the way your script is written you'll incorrectly return `0` instead of correctly returning `-1`.

Comment: I do understand what @CJK meant by his example. I was just testing it to see if it will still works with the 0 for the min but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

AppleScriptObjC can do it without any loop

```
use AppleScript version "2.5"
use framework "Foundation"

set numberList to {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
set nsList to current application's NSArray's arrayWithArray:numberList
set max to (nsList's valueForKeyPath:"@max.intValue") as integer
set min to (nsList's valueForKeyPath:"@min.intValue") as integer
set even to (nsList's filteredArrayUsingPredicate:(current application's NSPredicate's predicateWithFormat:"modulus:by:(intValue,2) == 0")) as list
set odd to (nsList's filteredArrayUsingPredicate:(current application's NSPredicate's predicateWithFormat:"modulus:by:(intValue,2) == 1")) as list
```